# Connection refused error Python

Tags: python, sockets, connection

I'm using python on Mac and for some reason the connection is being refused when I try to run the server. Here is the code for both the Client and Server. I am trying to make it so that the user can login to a login system through the client side. I also wish to be able to make it so that when the user log's into an account their password is automatically saved to a .txt document. Anyone know how i can do this? Thanks for reading.

Client code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)



print("Waiting for connection")



s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 4000))  

data = s.recv(1024).decode()#max number of bytes recv

print ("data from server", data)

message = str(input("Send: ->"))

s.send(message.encode())

s.close()

input("\n\n press enter to close")



users = {}

status = ""



def displayMenu():

    status = input("Are you registered user? Please write yes or no. Press q to quit")

    if status == "yes":

        oldUser()

    elif status == "no":

        newUser()



def newUser():

    createLogin = input("Create login name: ")



    if createLogin in users:

        print("\nLogin name already exist!\n")

    else:

        createPassw = input("Create password: ")

        users[createLogin] = createPassw

        print("\nUser created\n")



def oldUser():

    login = input("Enter login name: ")

    passw = input("Enter password: ")



    if login in users and users[login] == passw:

        print("\nLogin successful! Your credentials have been saved.\n")

    else:

        print("\nUser doesn't exist or wrong password!\n")



while status != "q":

    displayMenu()
```

server code:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print("Listening: ")

s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 4000))
s.listen(10) #listen to 1 connection at a time
c, addr = s.accept()  
print ("Connection from: ", addr)
message = input("Send: ->")
c.sendall(message.encode())
data = c.recv(1024).decode()#max number of bytes recv
print("data from client ", data)

c.close()
input("\n\n press enter to close")
```

Comment: You probably want to clarify what you mean with `the connection is being refused when I try to run the server`. Either the server fail to run or runs. In the 1st case the connection cannot be refused when you try to run the server because it doesn't. In the 2nd case the server runs and the connection the client attempts is refused. If you also post what actual errors happen, people may be able to have a look into it.

Comment: can you share your traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Open the two programs in separate shell.
First run server program.
Then run your client program while the server program is still running.

It will solve the connection refused error.
Let me know if it worked:)

Comment: yes this worked thanks! :) do you know how i can implement a list within this program?

Comment: Ok I saw your another question. Is it necessary that the saved password to be stored into a .txt file. What you can also do is use sqlite3 to create database. If you want help with that I can help you.

Comment: Hi, yes that'd be great help if you could thanks! Would it be easier to message over email or on here? I didn't manage to complete what I had to do as I couldn't work out how to do it so your help would be greatly appreciated.